# Multiple dropdowns, combination check and filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript / jQuery, I'm trying to build a "combination checker" that will take the values of three (but can be more) dropdown lists and filter the options based on a supplied list of allowed combinations.

For example:

**DROPDOWNS**
**Field 1:**
- value_1
- value_2

**Field 2:**
- value_3

**Field 3:**
- value_4
- value_5

**COMBINATIONS**
- value_1, value_3, value_5
- value_1, value_3, value_4
- value_2, value_3, value_5

When a user selects **Field 3 - value_4**, the unavailable options will be disabled - ie, Field 1 - value_2 (there is no combination that allows value_2 and value_4 to be selected together).

It would be really great if someone could provide some pointers on how this can be achieved or just provide a fresh perspective - I'm going round in circles on this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the valid combinations in a javascript array.

```
var combinations = [[value1, value3, value5], [value1, value3, value4], [value2, value3, value5]];
```

You can then monitor changes with the [jQuery change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and remove all entries in the dropdown, and then add the permitted entries only.

There is no way to disable a dropdown entry in particular (you can only disable/enable the whole dropdown), so you'll have to remove the non allowed ones.

Comment: Yea, that's kind of what I had in mind.  Where I'm mostly struggling is with figuring out which values can be added back in.